# Magento Affiliate Integration: Update existing field

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

is there a specific magento function which updates the Referred By field in the Magento User Admin Panel? I would like to execute this function once during the registration, however have trouble finding where this maybe located.

I then want to use this particular function to add a custom email address into that field during registration.